# SVG transform as a stylesheet property (as opposed to CSS transform)

Tags: css, svg, rotation, transform

## Background:

I am long familar with *CSS 2D rotate transforms*:

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

I am much less familiar with *SVG 2D rotate transforms*:

```
transform="rotate(45, 0, 0)"
```

But I do know that

- *CSS 2D rotate transforms* use the `50%, 50%` point of the element as the rotational axis; whereas
- *SVG 2D rotate transforms* use the `x, y` co-ordinates supplied in the 2nd and 3rd parameters as the rotational axis

---

## Question:

When I put SVGs together I generally try to avoid inline attributes and use CSS rules instead.

I understand from **MDN**, that:

> As of SVG2, transform is a presentation attribute, meaning it can be
>   used as a CSS property. However, be aware that there are some
>   difference in syntax between the CSS property and the attribute. See
>   the documentation for the CSS property transform for the specific
>   syntax to use in that case.
>
> **Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

I don't know if I am understanding this correctly or not.

- I know I can declare *SVG transform* as an in-element attribute
- I know I can declare *CSS transform* as a stylesheet property

But can I declare *SVG transform* as a stylesheet property in the manner of these SVG-attributes-as-stylesheet-properties:

```
.badge {

 fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);`
 stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);`
 stroke-width: 10;
}
```

**ie.** something like: `transform: rotate(45, 0, 0)` ?

Or can I only declare *CSS transform* as a stylesheet property when describing transforms of SVG elements?

I ask only because the former doesn't appear to be working, and I'm not sure if it's me or Firefox.

Comment: no, you cannot use the SVG syntax inside CSS. `transform: rotate(45, 0, 0)` should be invalid (it's the case when I am testing it) unless there is some exception

Comment: In a stylesheet, use CSS syntax; in an attribute, use attribute syntax. That's it.

Comment: Thank you, @TemaniAfif - that's what I was concluding, but I wanted to be certain. If you want to post your comment above as an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: I will leave this to more experienced users in SVG, probably there is some special cases.

Comment: As Temani states, the CSS group decided not to include that version of `rotate()` in the list of supported transform functions.  Also, "syntax differences" refers to other things as well.  For instance, CSS requires that values have units.  So the equivalent of `transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)"` in CSS would be `transform: rotate(45deg); transform-origin: 50px 50px;`

Comment: That was the perfect answer, @PaulLeBeau - _exactly_ what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain by way of example the nuances and differences of the transformation of 2D CSS vs SVG. 
SVG uses absolute coordinates that are calculated from the upper left corner of the SVG canvas.

[image]

Where indicate the coordinates of the center of rotation `transform="rotate(0 100 100)"`, then around them the SVG element will rotate

**transform="rotate(0 100 100)"**
*Animation starts after clicking on SVG canvasemphasized text*

```html
<style>
#rectGroup {
  fill: crimson;
}
</style>
<svg id="svg1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="border:1px solid gray;">
<g id="rectGroup">
<rect width="100px" height="50px" x="50px" y="50px" rx="10"/> 
<circle cx="60px" cy="75px" r="5px" style="fill:gold;"/> 
  
<animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
 type="rotate"
 begin="svg1.click"
 dur="2s"
 values="0 100 100;360 100 100"
 repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
</g>
<circle cx="100px" cy="75px" r="5px" fill="black"/>
<circle cx="100px" cy="100px" r="5px" fill="yellowgreen"/>

<polyline points="0,75 200,75" stroke="gray" />
<polyline points="100,0 100,200" stroke="gray" />
</svg>
```

**transform="rotate(0 100 75)"**

```html
<style>
#rectGroup {
  fill: crimson;
}
</style>
<svg id="svg1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="border:1px solid gray;">
<g id="rectGroup">
<rect width="100px" height="50px" x="50px" y="50px" rx="10"/> 
<circle cx="60px" cy="75px" r="5px" style="fill:gold;"/> 
  
<animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
 type="rotate"
 begin="svg1.click"
 dur="2s"
 values="0 100 75;360 100 75"
 repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
</g>
<circle cx="100px" cy="75px" r="5px" fill="black"/>
<circle cx="100px" cy="100px" r="5px" fill="yellowgreen"/>

<polyline points="0,75 200,75" stroke="gray" />
<polyline points="100,0 100,200" stroke="gray" />
</svg>
```

In CSS, a block model that uses the coordinates of the center of rotation relative to the parent container 
This saves us from calculating and specifying coordinates exactly as it is done in SVG, which greatly simplifies the task.
But the main question was whether SVG syntax could be used to place it in CSS rules.
**The short answer is no.**

But SVG is well integrated with CSS rules.

1. External style sheet
   The examples below repeat the SVG transformation examples.

Rotation around the center of the parent container

```
transform: rotate(135deg);
transform-origin: center;
```

```html
<style>
#rectGroup {
  fill: crimson;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

</style>
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="border:1px solid gray;">
<g id="rectGroup">
<rect width="100px" height="50px" x="50px" y="50px" rx="10"/> 
<circle cx="60px" cy="75px" r="5px" style="fill:gold;"/>
</g>
<circle cx="100px" cy="75px" r="5px" fill="black"/>
<circle cx="100px" cy="100px" r="5px" fill="yellowgreen"/>

<polyline points="0,75 200,75" stroke="gray" />
<polyline points="100,0 100,200" stroke="gray" />
</svg>
```

2. Styles inside the SVG file

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="border:1px solid gray;">
<style>
#rectGroup {
  fill: crimson;
 transform-origin:center;
}
</style>
<g id="rectGroup" style="transform:rotate(135deg);">
<rect width="100px" height="50px" x="50px" y="50px" rx="10"/> 
<circle cx="60px" cy="75px" r="5px" style="fill:gold;"/> 
</g>
<circle cx="100px" cy="75px" r="5px" fill="black"/>
<circle cx="100px" cy="100px" r="5px" fill="yellowgreen"/>

<polyline points="0,75 200,75" stroke="gray" />
<polyline points="100,0 100,200" stroke="gray" />
</svg>
```

3. Styles in SVG  presentation attributes's

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="border:1px solid gray;">

<g id="rectGroup" style="fill:crimson;transform-origin:center;transform:rotate(135deg);">
<rect width="100px" height="50px" x="50px" y="50px" rx="10"/> 
<circle cx="60px" cy="75px" r="5px" style="fill:gold;"/> 
</g>
<circle cx="100px" cy="75px" r="5px" fill="black"/>
<circle cx="100px" cy="100px" r="5px" fill="yellowgreen"/>

<polyline points="0,75 200,75" stroke="gray" />
<polyline points="100,0 100,200" stroke="gray" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for: _"[...] the [...] question was whether SVG syntax could be used to place it in CSS rules. The [...] answer is no."_